SSIS dynamically Execute Package Task: Package Name is missing
I want to run multiple packages using Execute Package Task. There is a table in database saves the package names. I create a SQL Query Task first. The query result is a list of package names:

Then I created 2 variables. A Variable called List, its type is system.Object. It is used to save this list of package names.


Then I added a Loop each Container to read through each record in the List variable. And give each record's value to a variable called Name (type is string)


Then I put a Execute Package Task into the Loop each Container. And set the Expression to let the PackageName to use Name variable's value. But after I clicked OK, it gave me a warning:' Package Name is missing'. Does it mean the Name variable cannot pass value to this Execute Package Task? I haven't deployed this project to SQL Server database. I just run it in VS2015 development tool. Do I have to deploy all the packages first?



Are you certain the package name is being populated in the variable correctly?  You can debug and step through (or what I used that I have found faster is a quick C# task that outputs the variable values in a message box for debugging (and I disable when going to PROD).

The problem is, I just clicked ok after I've done the Expression. And then it says Package Name is missing. I even haven't Run the package yet.

And I used a Execute SQL query Task to replace the Execute Package Task. The SQL will write log into a table in database, with the values in Name variable. It can run successfully and the value in Name are the correct package names.

Put a default/dummy value in a variable so the expression puts some name there (then VS wont see a value missing) it just wont use that one when it starts looping and populates with your loop value.

For the execute package task, set DelayValidation to True.  This will postpone validation for the task until runtime.


This works. Thanks
